# sql search in multi columns

Tags: sql, sql-server

I want to search only in 2016 year.

```
select from products 
WHERE year="2016" 
and name like '%"& name &"%' 
or size like '%"& Size &"%'
```

Comment: actually what are you trying to do?

Comment: Double quotes are for identifiers, use single quotes for literals. (In your case `"2016"` is read as a column with that name...)

Comment: Please provide sample datas, desire output.

Comment: Sounds like `name` column holds multiple name values, ditto for `size` i.e. 1NF violation (not to mention temporal data stored as text).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Put parens around your `or`-ed conditions, and change the double quotes to single quotes for the year (as suggested by jarlh):

```
select from products 
WHERE year='2016' 
and (
    name like '%"& name &"%' 
    or size like '%"& Size &"%'
)
```

*Oh and in case this is VB.NET and you got `name` and `Size` from a parameter or something, make sure you are [escaping them](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6760237/how-in-vb-net-we-can-encode-string-for-sql) to prevent SQL injection (if this not already done somewhere else).*

Comment: thanks for answer.

Answer (score 0):

No need for double quotes, or any quotes in the `LIKE`.

```
SELECT *
FROM products 
WHERE year = '2016' 
AND (name LIKE '%name%' OR size LIKE '%size%'
```